# How do I create relevant keyword search?

Tags: views, search

I created a view and fetched the content from a content type. I created an exposed filter with two fields (*title* and *body*) using contextual filters.

Search works for exact match keywords, but it doesn't work with similar keywords. For example, for *timesheet* and *application* it works fine, but if I search using the wrong spelling (for example, *timeshet* or *appliction*), it doesn't work.

How do I create a keyword relevant search?

Answer (score 1):

You would need [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) and [Search API Solr](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) for this, along with a Solr instance to get relevancy scoring and support for fuzzy searching (e.g. iphone iphane etc).

- https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api
- https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr

It is mostly configurable from the Drupal UI.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I am checking, Is relevancy search possible without using solr?

Comment: No. Without Solr or equivalent, you won't be able to do a search like that.

Comment: I believe [Search API Database Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_db) does support relevance, but Solr is better in fuzzy matching

Comment: I have enabled the 'Search api database search' module and created the views with the indexed values, But expose filter is not appearing i have tried this field 'Search: Fulltext search (exposed)' from both the place FILTER CRITERIA and CONTEXTUAL FILTERS